# How to connect with sshd?

Tags: telnet, sshd

I need to connect my laptop (Mac OS) to my Virtual Box (Debian) via sshd and then test telnet in Debian. Problem is I can't seem to connect via sshd.

I get

> sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path

when I run

```
sshd root@192.xxx.xx.xx
```

But if I use an absolute path as suggested I get this instead:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd root@192.xxx.xx.xxx
```

> Extra argument root@192.xxx.xx.xxx

What is the problem and how does one connect via sshd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sshd` is the dæmon program that listens to SSH port, then let incoming connections in.

You want to use `ssh` (without "d") as a client to connect to a remote machine:

```
usr/sbin/ssh root@192.xxx.xx.xxx
```

Comment: Think I misunderstood the instructions I got (they're very unclear I have to say), but at least I know there's no need to use sshd but ssh only. Thanks.